# Helm template need to get and set value in dict

Tags: go, templates, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I have the following data in my function $newdict

```
   modules:
     module1: 
      enabled: true
     module2:
      enabled: false
     module3:
      enabled: true, etc
```

What is need to do is : check if module1 enabled, then set enabled for module2 as well. What I tried in _helpers.tpl file:

```
  {{- range $key, $value := $newdict -}}
  {{ if and (eq $key "module1") (eq "enabled" "true") }}
  {{ $_ := set $newdict $key "module2" (eq "enabled" "true") }} 
  {{ end }}  
  {{ end }}
  {{ toYaml $newdict }}
```

helm lint doesn't show any errors, but the changes are not reflected in $newdict

This thing is needed for deployment.yaml to deploy init container:

```
     initContainers:
  {{- $mycustom := (include "myfunction" . ) | fromYaml}}
  {{- range $key, $value := $mycustom }}
    {{- if $value.enabled }}
    - name: init-{{ $key }}-myinit
```

So, in the end, I need to deploy init container "module2" only if "module1" is also deployed

Answer (score 1):

Helm's general style is that values are immutable.  I'd avoid the `set` function here and stick to a more functional style.

It may help your setup that you can directly index things in dict (map) structures, or use the standard Go template `index` function.  You don't need to iterate through the entire dict looking for a key.  So if you're sure the variable has keys `module1` and `module2` then you can simplify the final logic to:

```yaml
initContainers:
{{- if or .Values.module1.enabled .Values.module2.enabled }}
  - name: init-module2-myinit
  ...
{{- end }}
```

Your setup hints at having more init containers; `module1`, `module2`, and `module3` would each have their own init containers, but you also want to emit `module2`'s whenever `module1` is turned on regardless of the `module2` setting.  One way to approach this might be to write a helper function that decided whether a given module was enabled:

```
{{/* Decide whether some module is enabled.  Call with a list of
     two items, the values structure to examine and the specific
     module key.  Returns either the string "true" or an empty
     string. */}}
{{- define "is-module-enabled" -}}
{{- $modules := index . 0 -}}
{{- $key := index . 1 -}}
{{- if index $modules $key "enabled" -}}
true
{{- else if and (eq $key "module2") $modules.module1.enabled -}}
true
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
```

```yaml
initContainers:
{{- range $key := .Values.modules -}}
{{- if include "is-module-enabled" (list .Values.modules $key) }}
  - name: init-{{ $key }}-myinit
  ...
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. yes, you are right, I have more init containers (about 10), these 3 are just an example. can you please specify how can I refer to my $newdict with the data from the "is-module-enabled" function? I mean at the moment, it's not clear where this index comes from. and can I refer to ".Values.modules" from deployment.yaml?

Comment: With the structure in the individual question, I think you could pass `$newdict.modules` as the first parameter to the helper function at the end.  As I've shown it, it will use the top-level `modules:` key from your chart's `values.yaml` or a `helm install -f` values file.